# Jmeter - measure OS Process Sampler executing duration

Tags: jmeter, duration, measurement, execution-time, assertion

I have OS Process Sampler to invoke OS command via JMeter. I need to measure total time of script execution and define response assertion. Asseriont should fail if measured execution duration exceeds given limit.

How can I do this using JMeter? I can't see any possibility to measure execution duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "Duration Assertion" as a child of your sampler.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion